# WebClient.DownloadFile will not write to network share on linux system

Tags: c#, webclient

This is not actually my own code and I don't have a way to change and compile it, but I'm trying to debug a program and all it does is download a file and store it locally. It's literally something like:

```
try {
  using var client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadFile( URL, filename );
  log("File successfully downloaded");
}
catch (Exception e) {
  log("Download failed.");
}
```

URL and filename are passed as arguments so I can actually change those. If filename is a local path, like for instance "/home/myusername/test.dat", it works fine. So I know the code works. But if filename resides on a mounted NAS (ie "/mnt/NetworkDrive/test.dat"), it gives the "Download failed" error.

It looks like the user the code runs under, does not have write permission to the mounted network share. But I mounted the network share with the **noperm** option, and creating files manually always succeeds, no matter what user I try it as.

The network share is mounted through /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.131/sharedfolder /mnt/NetworkDrive cifs guest,_netdev,vers=1.0,noperm 0 0
```

Where 192.168.1.131 is ofcourse the IP address of the NAS. It's an older NAS which uses SMBv1 which is why I mount it with "vers=1.0" And like I said, I can access the NAS just fine. I can create files and delete files from the command prompt without problems. As any user. But the above code fails to write to it.

What could be causing this?

Again, this is not my code so I can't change anything. But I'm sure the code is fine and something else is at play here.

**UPDATE #1 (Mar 31)**
So it turns out writing to the NAS is denied, which is weird because if I test it (from the command prompt), I can create and write to a file on the NAS without problems. As root or any other user.

**UPDATE #2 (Mar 31)**
I've been troubleshooting all day and I'm at a loss. Any user has full access to the NAS and can read/write/delete/create/modify files. I can create a new user on the system and it too has full access. But WebClient.DownloadFile **always** fails with a "Permission Denied" as soon as it tries to write the downloaded file to the NAS. If I write it to a local path, it works fine.

Comment: can you try `log($"Download failed. {e.Message}");` and check the reason?

Comment: Had to install dotnet en download the source and build it. But I get "An exception occured during a WebClient request".

Comment: Did some more debugging and the error is actually `Access to the path '/mnt/NetworkDrive/test.dat' is denied`.

Comment: if you cannot change source code, then nothing can be done. if you can, then you could try other methods such as httpclient(download to local then copy to share folder for example), instead of webclient.

Comment: Ok, but the real question is, why can **all** users write to the mounted share from the command line, but the program can't?

Comment: we are only interested if the problem can easy be reproducible, by us. first you need make sure no other reason causing problem. you can start a demo project and check various kinds of operations in C#, like file write simply without downloading. after trying, you can edit you question, removing the part about existing software, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Mono or .NET Core? Which version? What if writing directly to `//192.168.1.131/sharedfolder` (UNC path) without mounting?

Comment: .Net Core. Will have to try writing directly later.